# Does $x$ irreducible in ring $R$ imply $(x)$ maximal ideal of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I was studying for my final exam of abstract algebra and, after seeing that $p$ prime element of a ring $R$ is equivalent as saying the ideal $(p)\unlhd R$ is prime, I came up with the assumption that something similar might happend with the irreducible elements and the maximal ideals, but this is not said anywhere in my course book so I may be wrong. So my question is, is this statement true?

> Being $R$ a commutative unital ring, and $0\neq x\in\mathbb{R\setminus R^\times}$, then: $$x \text{ irreducible in $R$} \Longleftrightarrow (x) \text{ is maximal ideal of $R$}$$

Maybe this is only verified under certain extra conditions of $R$ (for example, being PID or UFD or some kind of special ring). Is my assumption true in general? If not, could you give me a counter example? It would be nice to have a proof if it's true. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Not in general, I think. Take $R = k[x,y]$ and let $x$ be, well, $x$.

Comment: Also, take $x$ that is irreducible but not prime. Then $(x)$ is not prime and, a fortiori, not maximal.

Comment: @Gae.S. So would it be true inside rings where primes and irreducibles are the same? (Fields, Euclidean Domains, Principal Ideal Domains and Unique Factorisation Domains)

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso As Jeroen has shown, not in UFDs. In fields this is vacuously true. In PIDs which aren't fields it's true, because in general $x$ is irreducible if and only if $(x)$ is a maximal element of the family of proper non-zero principal ideals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x \in R$ is irreducible if and only if the ideal $(x)$ is maximal *among proper principal ideals*.  The proof is straightforward.

Thus if there exist proper ideals in $R$ which are not principal, then there will exist irreducible elements whose principal ideals are not maximal ideals.

Comment: $x\Bbb{Q}$ is not principal in $(\Bbb{Z}+x\Bbb{Q}[x])/x^2\Bbb{Q}[x]$, 
the irreducibles $p+ax$ are maximal ideals.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest counterexample is $R=\mathbb Z[x]$. Then $(x) \subset (2,x)$ is not maximal.